# Borel Zero-One Law for a sequence of constants

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I'm working on a problem and need some intuition to get unstuck, thanks in advance.

So, we are given a sequence of iid random variables $ \{X_n, n \geq 1\}$. Then we have $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence of constants.

We need to show:

$$P \{ [X_n > a_n] \text{ i.o.}  \} = 
\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{iff } \sum_n P[X_1 >a_n] < \infty \\
      1 & \text{iff } \sum_n P[X_1 >a_n] = \infty
   \end{cases}
$$
**My intuition:**

It is clear that this problem is related to Borel Zero-One Law.

So, I think of defining the event $A_n = X_1 > a_n$ and then, claim that by the one-zero law:

$$P \{ [A_n] \text{ i.o.}  \} = 
\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{iff } \sum_n P(A_n) < \infty \\
      1 & \text{iff } \sum_n P(A_n) = \infty
\end{cases}
$$
However, I think I'm missing something or ignoring something by not considering that what I'm asked to show involves the sum of terms having $X_1$ only: i.e. $\sum_n P[X_1 > a_n]$.

Any thought you may have about it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's just that $P(X_n > a_n) = P(X_1 > a_n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any intuition that may support your claim? 
I think since all the X_n are iid, it's not necessarily true that i.e. $P[X_1>a_1 ] = P[X_2 > a_2]$ considering that the sequence $\{ a_n\}$ can be any sequence of different constants. I don't think $a_n = k, \forall n$.  However, If that is the case, then since all $X_n$ are iid, $P[X_n > a_n] = P[X_1 > a_n]$. But then why they used $a_n$? They could had used simply k. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A_n = \{X_n > a_n\}$. Then you'll agree that what we are trying to calculate is $P(A_n \text{ i.o})$. These events are independent (since the random variables are independent) so by the Borell-Cantelli Lemmas, $P(A_n \text{ i.o})$ is $0$ or $1$ depending on whether or not the sum

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(A_n) $$

converges. But since $P(A_n) = P(X_n > a_n) = P(X_1 > a_n)$ what we have is

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(A_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P(X_1 > a_n). $$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Could you please help me understanding why is it that  $P(X_n > a_n) = P(X_1 > a_n)$ ?

Comment: @htennek2k They have the same distribution. If their cdf is $F$ then these probabilities are both $1 - F(a_n)$.

Comment: Thanks. I see that. I guess my question is whether $a_n = k$ (some $k$) for all $n$. ?

Comment: @htennek2k that's a special case. Another one is where $a_n = n$ and $X_n$ is non-negative. Then $\sum_n P(X_1 > n) < \infty$ iff $E(X_n) < \infty$. This is a good exercise and basically amounts to the integral test for convergence of series.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.  Just please, need a little more help.
Lets take the case you mentioned $a_n = n$, then, It's hard for me to see that $P(X_n > n) = P(X_{n+k} > n+k)$. Unless... we think of very large n. Is that the trick?

Comment: $P(X_n > n) = P(X_m > n)$ not $P(X_m > m)$.

Comment: Ohhh. I see the light now.  Yeah, I'm feeling dummy now. But I appreciate your time and patience.  This is just the subscript of the RV. $A_n$ has the same distribution as $X_1$ Thanks!.